# Creating Table in dataset in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics

I want to create a Table for my *dataset* in **BigQuery**. I want to upload *CSV file*. When I upload it and clicked on "create table" it is saying:

> unexpected error. Tracking number c986854671035387

What is this error and How can I solve this? (I also upgraded my **BigQuery** to 90 days *free trial*).

Comment: You should try looking up the documentation for the error/tracking number. That's the only clue in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the data inside CSV. If it has column names and no faulty records.

you can download any sample CSV file from here and try

http://www.mytrapture.com/sampledata/